# Qt C++ Android compilation bionic header error

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to compile a plain C++ static library for Android with Qt creator. However i'm receiving this error:

```
#error Bionic header ctype.h does not define either _U nor _CTYPE_U
```

I'm using android ndk r10b, Java jdk1.8.0_20, adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702. I'm compiling with Qt 5.3 for Android armv7 and Android GCC (arm-4.8).

I'm including several linux libraries: jsoncpp, libuuid, libbluetooth and libzmq.

The problem comes when i add the following include path:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include
```

I need that include path for the above mentioned libraries.

If anybody could point me into a certain direction i would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you add your systems include path not the Android system include path. There is no reason to add this include path if you building for Android. If you need a library for you Android environment you need to compile and deploy it to your Android toolchain.

See for example how I install Android libs: https://github.com/strahlex/QtQuickVcp/wiki/Installing-protobuf-and-zeromq

Comment: Yea i figured it out some time ago, but thanks for your answer +1. What i did is, i removed the dependencies by adding the source code and compiling everything together for android.